Place Header with bulleted List After Specific Text in Google Doc Using Script
I'm attempting to have a button (linked image or text) users can use to insert a templated paragraph of text into a specific section of a google doc. The templated text is a Header which has a checklist checkbox (when used, strikes out line), and includes an expandable bulleted list.
Example of the text script should input
I've mostly been able to build out how I want the template text to look, but haven't found a solution online for placing it after specific text while remaining formatted, and also making the header a checklist. The text it should appear under is "New Items:".
I've found ways to place unformatted text in specific areas, and ways to create lists that are all checkboxes, but nothing that includes the combinations I'm looking for.
I've found ways to place the cursor in a specific location and ways to "findtext", but none that I was able to make work along with the specific formatted text I'm using.
Here's an example google doc that includes the script I have so far.
Here's the script so far:
function insertText() {
  var headerFormatOn = {"BOLD": true, "BACKGROUND_COLOR": "#000000", "FOREGROUND_COLOR": "#FFFFFF"};
  ///var formatOn = {"BOLD": true, "BACKGROUND_COLOR": "#000000", "FOREGROUND_COLOR": "#FFFFFF"};
  ///var formatOff = {"BOLD": false, "BACKGROUND_COLOR": "#000000", "FOREGROUND_COLOR": "#FFFFFF"};
  var header = "Enter_Item_Title_Here"
  var bulletBody = ": ___________"
  var bulletOneHeader = "Agenda Item Owner(s): ___________"
  var bulletTwoHeader = "Discussant: ___________"
  var bulletThreeHeader = "Discussion Date: ___________"
  var bulletFourHeader = "External follow up: ___________"
  var bulletFiveHeader = "Notes: ___________"
  var bulletSixHeader = "Action Items: ___________"

  var attributes1 = Object.entries(headerFormatOn).reduce((o, [k, v]) => Object.assign(o, {[k]: v}), {});
  ///var attributes2 = Object.entries(formatOn).reduce((o, [k, v]) => Object.assign(o, {[k]: v}), {});
  ///var attributes3 = Object.entries(formatOff).reduce((o, [k, v]) => Object.assign(o, {[k]: v}), {});

  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getActiveTab().asDocumentTab().getBody();
  var text1 = cursor.appendParagraph(header);
  text1.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3);
  ///var text2 = cursor.insertText(bulletBody);
  ///text2.setAttributes(attributes3);
  var text3 = cursor.appendListItem(bulletOneHeader);
    //text3.setAttributes(attributes2);
    text3.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);

  var text4 = cursor.appendListItem(bulletTwoHeader);
    //text4.setAttributes(attributes2);
    text4.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
  var text5 = cursor.appendListItem(bulletThreeHeader);
  text5.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
  var text6 = cursor.appendListItem(bulletFourHeader);
  text6.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
  var text7 = cursor.appendListItem(bulletFiveHeader);
  text7.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
  var text8 = cursor.appendListItem(bulletSixHeader);
  text8.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
  var text9 = cursor.appendListItem(bulletSixHeader);
  text9.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
}

I have a feeling some of it might have to do with "append" vs "insert", or some of the variations I've read about in my searching, but I haven't been able to figure out which pieces need to change in order for it to work.

Kindly correct me if I'm wrong. From what I understand, the question has three parts, with the first one being adding the generated template from the script to the place where the cursor is in the document; the second is changing the lists to checkboxes; and the last one is formatting the text to what you want. Would that be correct?

I suppose that's true. Some clarifications, in case it helps ensure we're on the same page:
It doesn't have to be based around where the cursor is, I just tried that approach. I also tried out using placement based on finding certain text. So any method that works! It should be placed beneath the "New Items" text of the doc.
Only the header should have a checkbox - not the whole list.
The formatting I have, but haven't been able to retain it along with adding the other factors. So, that could be considered another "part" if the formatting would need to be rewritten to make it work.

I appreciate the explanation. I'll post an answer for the first part. For the second and third parts, please post a new question about them afterwards so that it'll be one question per post.

I was able to get the first and third parts of the question, as they're related to one another. As for the header should have a checkbox - not the whole list, kindly post that as a new question so that other community members would also be able to check it out.

You are correct with the statement I have a feeling some of it might have to do with "append" vs "insert". From what I know, appendParagraph(paragraph) and appendListItem(listItem) are meant to add on something at the end of the document, while insertParagraph(childIndex, paragraph) and insertListItem(childIndex, listItem) are to add something wherever you'd like, in this case after the "New Items" text.
Here's a modified version of your script that should achieve what you'd like:
function insertText() {
  var header = "Enter_Item_Title_Here"
  var bulletOneHeader = "Agenda Item Owner(s): ___________"
  var bulletTwoHeader = "Discussant: ___________"
  var bulletThreeHeader = "Discussion Date: ___________"
  var bulletFourHeader = "External follow up: ___________"
  var bulletFiveHeader = "Notes: ___________"
  var bulletSixHeader = "Action Items: ___________"
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getActiveTab().asDocumentTab().getBody();
  var pr = cursor.findText("New Items:").getElement().getParent();
  var i = cursor.getChildIndex(pr) + 1;
  cursor.insertParagraph(i, header).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3);
  cursor.insertListItem(i + 1, bulletOneHeader).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET).setAttributes({ [DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]: true });
  cursor.insertListItem(i + 2, bulletTwoHeader).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET).setAttributes({ [DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]: true });
  cursor.insertListItem(i + 3, bulletThreeHeader).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET).setAttributes({ [DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]: true });
  cursor.insertListItem(i + 4, bulletFourHeader).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET).setAttributes({ [DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]: true });
  cursor.insertListItem(i + 5, bulletFiveHeader).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET).setAttributes({ [DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]: true });
  cursor.insertListItem(i + 6, bulletSixHeader).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET).setAttributes({ [DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]: true });
}


Note: I removed the unused lines from the code, and the output should be similar to the formatting that you want.


Let me know if you have any questions, and I'll be happy to help in any way I can!

Amazing, thank you so much, Saddles!
